# Radio button selection with primefaces

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, datatable

I have the following radio button-selectable datatable:

```
<h:form>

        <p:dataTable value="#{gerarDocumentoBacking.reclamantes}"
                     selection="#{gerarDocumentoBacking.reclamante}" var="re" rowKey="#{re.id}">
            <p:column headerText="Id">
                <h:outputText value="#{re.id}"/>
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Relamantes">
                <h:outputText value="#{re.nome}"/>
            </p:column>
            <p:column selectionMode="single"/>
        </p:dataTable>


        <p:commandButton value="Gerar" action="#{gerarDocumentoBacking.gerar}"/>
</h:form>
```

It displays all the rows and the radio button as expected. However, it's not setting the `reclamante` variable, as specified in the  `selection=` attribute.

The `setReclamante` method is available and public:

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class GerarDocumentoBacking implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private List<Reclamante> reclamantes;
private Reclamante reclamante;

@EJB
private ReclamanteService reclamanteService;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    reclamantes = reclamanteService.listar();
}

public String gerar() {
    System.out.println(reclamante.getNome());
    return null;
}

public Reclamante getReclamante() {
    return reclamante;
}

public void setReclamante(Reclamante reclamante) {
    this.reclamante = reclamante;
}
...
```

Using some IDE debugging, I could see the `setReclamante` method being called with a null value, so my `gerar` method is throwing a NullPointerException at line `System.out.println(reclamante.getNome());`. My datatable has the rowKey attribute and I know it's valid because it's being displayed in the datatable.

I need the command button outside the datatable because I intend to use other datatables inside this `h:form`.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. The page had a `<head>` tag instead of a `<h:head>`.